# how do I get the index from this function

Tags: swift, dictionary, charts

this is demo of iOS Charts library (LineChart) and I want to input my data instead of arc4random data.
My data is in Array so I have to approach with index but I can't understand the `(0..<count).map { (i) -> ChartDataEntry` code.

```
func setChartValues(_ count : Int = 24) {

    let values = (0..<count).map { (i) -> ChartDataEntry in
        let val = Double(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(count))+3)
        return ChartDataEntry(x: Double(i), y: val)
    }
    let set1 = LineChartDataSet(entries: values , label : "DataSet 1")
    let data = LineChartData(dataSet: set1)
    self.lineChartView.data = data
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you are new to iOS and swift. What you are looking for is an understanding of the functionning of closures in swift, **plus** the `map` function which is called an **high order function**

from apple doc ( https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/array/3017522-map ) :

> Returns an array containing the results of mapping the given closure over the sequence’s elements.

In other words it maps your array into another array, according to the trailing closure you passed as a parameter.

---

In your specific case here his how to read it :

1. `(0..<count)` : creates an array of `count` lengh

example : if `count = 4` then `(0..<count)` is `[0, 1, 2, 3]`

2. As said previously the `map` function will transform **each** of your element into another ( therefore keeping the length of the array ).

in your case `val = Double(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(count))+3)` will be equal to a random number calculated with `count` value, and create a new `ChartDataEntry` with this random value.

to sum it up the whole code is just saying "I will create a `count` length array of random `ChartDataEntry`", I guess as a mockup

---

I suggest you to read about closures here :

- https://medium.com/the-andela-way/closures-in-swift-8aef8abc9474

and high order functions ( such as `map(_:)` ) here :

- https://medium.com/@abhimuralidharan/higher-order-functions-in-swift-filter-map-reduce-flatmap-1837646a63e8

Comment: take a look at my edit, it answers your specific question

Answer (score 0):

let values = (0.. ChartDataEntry in
        let val = Double(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(count))+3)
     return ChartDataEntry(x: Double(i), y: val)
  }

The value mapped and return is you can say a hash function. (arc4random).
It index you are taking is just setting X axis of the chart like 0 , 1 ,2 etc...
and your graph Y it set according to the functions return (arc4random)